# How to get INSTANT RESPONSE from Quickbooks Desktop

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm using [quickbooks-php](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) to query/add customer from quickbooks desktop.

At this point, I want to write some rest apis to put new customer to quickbooks desktop and get instant response with customer's ID from QB.

I'm not sure even I can get instant reply from the qbxml query to quickbooks desktop.

What is the best experience for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the library you linked to, you can't. It uses the Web Connector, and the Web Connector doesn't support real-time communication with QuickBooks.

If you want to, you can either use the QuickBooks SDK directly (C#, but be aware you'll have a lot of wrapper code to write if you want to make that work over HTTP or via a web service/website of any sort) or use a third-party solution (e.g. Autofy).

Comment: thanks for your fast reply, I really like your posts on this platform about quickbooks. By the way where can I find php sdk samples to get instant reply from QBD? 
I'm writing apis using php so instant reply is the key point. Any suggestion would be very helpful

Comment: I have never seen any PHP integration with an instant response back from QuickBooks. It _might_ be do-able with something like Autofy. I sure wouldn't want to attempt it - QuickBooks is not reliable or available enough to make that a reliable/highly available solution in my experience.

Comment: I'm going query all the customer fullnames and save them to the database (duplicate of quickbooks customers for fullname field only). This will work with web connector as a back process. 
and api will get customer data from database and will return id from the database field - quickbooks_listid.
what's your opinion?

Comment: Yep, caching is the way I'd go. I'd cache the ListID, Name, and FullName of the customers.

Comment: nice to hear that I'm on the right way. One more quick question :P when I need to add new customer can I add customized ListID to quickbooks using quickbooks-php?

Comment: No, QuickBooks generates the ListIDs for you.

Comment: Actually that is the main point, to get ListID of the customer (just request add via web connector) then I need to query the quickbooks via web connector again?

Comment: No, you get it back in the response from the Web Connector, when you add it.

Comment: Thanks for your time, valuable discussion with you today. I need some research on it, still I'm not familiar enough with that quickbooks-php. Will take a look web connector examples again.